# I only want to pull in 1 match from my INNER JOIN query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am building a table using multiple INNER JOIN queries on other tables and one of my queries is returning multiple matches (correctly based on how this function works) but I really just need to pull back one match, the first it hits in the comparison will do.
Below is my code. On the last INNER JOIN query there can be several a.transaction_id = e.pb_trans_id matches in the repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions e table. Can I specify to just bring back 1 match?

'''

```
    SELECT

    distinct a.transaction_id,
    b.currency_id,
    h.SIG_CURRENCY_CODE,
    b.charge_id,
    c.charge_type_id,
    d.charge_group,
    e.account_name,
    f.sig_entity_label,
    e.trading_userid,
    e.exchange_id,
    e.tradeable_instr_name,
    g.underlying_sym_bloomberg,
    g.fut_expiration_date,
    e.trade_date,
    timestamp_table.timeformated,
    a.rate * a.basis_value AS dma_fee,
    SUM(A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER () as DMA_FEE_TOTAL
FROM
    repldoadm.ire_estimate_trans_map       a
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_estimate         b ON a.estimate_id = b.estimate_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_lu               c ON b.charge_id = c.charge_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charge_types_lu          d ON c.charge_type_id = d.charge_type_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions    e ON a.transaction_id = e.pb_trans_id --or a.transaction_id = e.PB_TRANS_ID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS timeformated,
            trans_id,
            pb_trans_id
        FROM
            repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions
    )                                      timestamp_table ON ( a.transaction_id = timestamp_table.trans_id or a.transaction_id = timestamp_table.pb_trans_id)
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.vw_ire_accounts              f ON e.account_name = f.pb_account_name
    LEFT JOIN stig_adm.instrument_universe           g ON e.tradeable_instr_name = g.short_name
    LEFT JOIN STIG_ADM.BBG_LU_CURRENCY h                ON c.payment_currency_id = h.SIG_CURRENCY_ID
```

'''

Comment: "...but I really just need to pull back one match..." - How you decide which one to pick? Just a random one, the one with a highest value of something, etc...

Comment: There is no `INNER JOIN` in your query so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler yep random is fine

Comment: @GordonLinoff i meant left join

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which row to return, perhaps `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function might help. Your current query - with addition of the named function - would be used as a subquery (or a CTE, as in my example), while the "final" query would return rows whose `RN = 1`.

Something like this:

```
WITH temp AS
      (  SELECT DISTINCT a.transaction_id,
                b.currency_id,
                h.SIG_CURRENCY_CODE,
                b.charge_id,
                c.charge_type_id,
                d.charge_group,
                e.account_name,
                f.sig_entity_label,
                e.trading_userid,
                e.exchange_id,
                e.tradeable_instr_name,
                TO_CHAR (e.create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
                g.underlying_sym_bloomberg,
                g.fut_expiration_date,
                e.trade_date,
                a.rate * a.basis_value AS dma_fee,
                SUM (A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER () AS DMA_FEE_TOTAL,
       -- this:
                ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY e.pb_trans_id ORDER BY e.create_ts DESC) rn
           FROM repldoadm.ire_estimate_trans_map a
                LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_estimate b
                   ON a.estimate_id = b.estimate_id
                LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_lu c
                   ON b.charge_id = c.charge_id
                LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charge_types_lu d
                   ON c.charge_type_id = d.charge_type_id
                LEFT JOIN repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions e
                   ON a.transaction_id = e.pb_trans_id
      )
SELECT t.*
  FROM temp t
 WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: You are mistaken. There must be no `GROUP BY` clause. I suppose you oversaw the SUM's OVER clause.

Comment: Whoops! Analytic form of the SUM function! I oversaw it, I was mistaken, I was warned, I fixed it. Thank you, @Thorsten!

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks for that. Upon reflection I would actually like to filter the record I return by a criteria. I have also updated the code in my initial snippet to provide what I am using now. I have a new LEFT JOIN statement to bring in a time field and this is actually what is causing me to bring in multiple records when I want just one (for this join only). How would I filter this join statement so that it returns the record with the latest time stamp in this field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join with a limit clause for this. For a lateral outer join I suggest to use `OUTER APPLY`, because unlike with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` you don't have to add a dummy `ON` clause to get this syntactically correct.

```
SELECT
    distinct a.transaction_id,
    b.currency_id,
    h.SIG_CURRENCY_CODE,
    b.charge_id,
    c.charge_type_id,
    d.charge_group,
    e.account_name,
    f.sig_entity_label,
    e.trading_userid,
    e.exchange_id,
    e.tradeable_instr_name,
    to_char(e.create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
    g.underlying_sym_bloomberg,
    g.fut_expiration_date,
    e.trade_date,
--    timestamp_table.timeformated,
    a.rate * a.basis_value AS dma_fee,
    SUM(A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER () as DMA_FEE_TOTAL
FROM
    repldoadm.ire_estimate_trans_map       a
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_estimate         b ON a.estimate_id = b.estimate_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charges_lu               c ON b.charge_id = c.charge_id
    LEFT JOIN repldoadm.ire_charge_types_lu          d ON c.charge_type_id = d.charge_type_id
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM repldoadm.vw_ire_trade_transactions tt
      WHERE tt.pb_trans_id = a.transaction_id
      FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ) e;
```